# Call dynamically loaded JS from Angular 6 Component

Tags: angular, angular6, typescript-typings

Following case: I have a foreign JS which I load from the web during runtime:

`<script src="https://someapi.com/foreignJS.js" type="text/javascript">`

After loading it, I need to call `foreignJS.init()`. In an older project (created as Angular 2 and subsequently upgraded to Angular 6) it worked using `declare var foreignJS: any` in the component and in typings.d.ts.

In the new project however - created with Angular 6 and angular-cli - there is no typings.d.ts and declaring in the component alone leaves me with `foreignJS` is undefined errors. I tried creating the typings.d.ts manually however this also didn't work. The JS is loaded correctly, checked in the console.

So the question is basically, how do I call a JavaScript function on a dynamically loaded script in Angular 6.

Update:
Actual problem was of course somewhere else. The script simply was not loaded yet at the point where I tried accessing it. And for some reason it only loaded after onInit had finished.

Comment: You see `foreignJS is undefined` at *run-time*, I presume?

Comment: Yes, basically as soon as it hits `console.log(foreignJS)`, I get the ReferenceError that foreignJS is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the edit, the actual problem lay elsewhere, the - for me satisfying - solution was to load the script in the 'parent' component.